# vpn and mproto proxy assign their access to azure private ip and not public ip

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

i want to set mtproto on my ubuntu AZURE but everytime make mtproto it only run in private ip and not public ip Started as [privateip:-****:***:**********] how can i delete private ip in azure and only use public ip or solve this problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove the private IP but you can assign a public IP for your Azure VM to make traffic go inside or outside of azure.

Firstly, you could assign a public IP via this flow on the portal: virtual machine-networking-network interface-IP configurations-click the IP version-enable the public IP for this NIC, then save it.

Secondly, edit the [configuration](https://github.com/p1ratrulezzz/MTProxy-1#configuration) `options.txt` file, set it to listen to all interfaces:

```
--address <public_ip_here> -- set IP address got from ifconfig OR set to 0.0.0.0 which means to listen to all interfaces
```

Finally, if you have NSG associated with your NIC or subnet, you can allow these ports from your client to access in the inbound rules. see [How to open ports to a virtual machine with the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal)

`-H 6968,6669 -- on which PORTS to listen for connections (You can set multiple ports using comma to split [see more](https://github.com/TelegramMessenger/MTProxy/issues/84#issuecomment-401022826))`

For more details, you could follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/p1ratrulezzz/MTProxy-1).